# How add a custom language to Power BI

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

Power BI by default supports the English language for display all names in a software web base.

How do I change to a custom language?

Comment: You can't. This is something that Microsoft will have to do.

Comment: thanks .@AndreyNikolov.There are companies that sell web-based PowerBI software in the language they want and sell it as a product.

Comment: This wasn't your question. Column titles is one thing, list of supported languages - another.

Comment: thanks @AndreyNikolov.It's a bit incomprehensible to me. I want all the words in the web powerbi software to be translated into a new language. Is this different from the text of my question?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can't add another item to the list of supported languages. However you can name your tables and columns any way you want. This will not affect system texts though (like menu items and texts in the filter pane for example). This is highly unlikely to be the case, so I have doubts about your statement. If you embed Power BI, technically you have access to the elements and you can change their texts, but this is extremely fragile, unsupported and hard to maintain. That's why I don't believe these companied did what you said.

Comment: thanks @AndreyNikolov.i am edit  question.i want change all name in power bi web base .